# How can we find min of two dates in apex

Tags: apex, date, math

I am trying to find min of two dates.

I used `MIN(date1,date2)` but I am facing the following error:
"Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void min(Date, Date)"

How can we find the minimum of two dates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably best to add your own static method either into the class where you need the minimum (make it private) or a utility class (make it public). This version handles nulls:

```
private static Date min(Date d1, Date d2) {
    if (d1 != null && d2 != null) return d1 < d2 ? d1 : d2;
    else if (d1 != null) return d1;
    else if (d2 != null) return d2;
    else return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard compare functions:

```
Boolean date1IsSmaller = false;
if (date1 < date2){
    date1IsSmaller = true;
}
```

Comment: This can throw NullPointerException if date1 or date2 is null.

Comment: Yes, it's a snippet. Just the important bits.